# How to reload JQuery everytime my URL change?

Tags: jquery

How to call this function everytime the URL change?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("URL change!");
});
```

I try something like, but it does not work :

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("URL change!");
  });
});
```

Comment: Well, this isn't the purpose of pseudo ready handler. Looks like a XY problem because anyway your code would work, so whatever you are trying to do, your issue is somewhere else

Comment: I added an example so you could understand how to keep track of the url and added some condition for you to better understand it. check my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the "old" URL in a cookie:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // read old saved URL
  var oldURL = $.cookie("oldURL");

  // check for URL change
  if (oldURL != window.location.href) {
    console.log("URL change!");
  }

  // save current URL in cookie
  $.cookie("oldURL", window.location.href);
});
```

The only thing is that on first call the cookie is empty so the URL change will happen also on first call.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to get the hash from a url you can do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var hash = window.location.hash;

     //Some condition
     if(hash=="foo"){
        //hash is foo do something

     }else if(hash=="bar"){
        //hash is bar do something

     }else{
        //hash is not foo nor bar : do something
     }
    console.log(hash);
});
```

if you need to get the full url then use `window.location.href` instead

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = window.location.href;
    console.log(url);
});
```

Now if you want to check for hashchange event you can the following, although hashchange is for jQuery mobile

```
 $( window ).hashchange(function() {
    var hash = location.hash;
    console.log(hash);
 });

$( window ).hashchange();
```

If you want to keep track of the previous url you might want to use `cookie` instead.

About your question **How to reload JQuery everytime my URL change?** jQuery is reloaded every page load so if you only want to know a hash from the url and do some stuff with that hash value my first example will do the job :)